# How do I verify if someone is a facebook user

Tags: laravel, facebook

I'm building a laravel app that is using a admin user registration approval system.  Once an admin approves the registration, I'd like the users to verify on their profile page that they are members of facebook and linkedin.  I see a bunch of stuff about user creation and login, but not about verification.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: would be better if you uae login with facebook or login with linkedIn

Comment: Actually, you have to have a certain license to be an approved user.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: make them login with facebook.. use Socialite..

Comment: There is no specific “verification” option offered by those networks; but if you make the user login using those networks, that would be implicit verification that they have an account there …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with Laravel Socialite, this can be achieved...

Once your users are logged in and approved by admin, you could add a facebook button to use the Socialite login functionality, but with some custom work.

In SocialAuthController.php

Find the handleFacebookCallback method

In my example i have the method named as handleProvider, but it works just the same

```
public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{

    // First we are going to get the user data from facebook
    $social_user = Socialite::driver($provider)->fields([
        'name', 'email'
    ])->user();

  //Now we make the logic
    if (Auth::check()) {  //if the user is logged in
        $userID = Auth::user()->id; //then we get the user ID

        $user = User::where('id', $userID)->first(); //Prepare the model for update

    //And finally we just start to update each field in DB (you need to create this fields)
        $user->fb_email = $social_user->email;
        $user->avatar = $social_user->avatar;
        $user->fb_id = $social_user->id;
        $user->save();

        return $this->authAndRedirect($user); // This is to redirect the user 

    }
}
```

With this you can make the users link their accounts in your app with facebook...

But keep in mind that also you'll need to handle with the else, the rest of the code for creating a new account if you are going to allow users to register with facebook. Otherwise, you only need to add the facebook button in the profile page of your users to link with their respective fb account.

The button can be like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('social.auth', 'facebook') }}" class="btn btn-social btn-just-icon btn-link"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
```

also you would need to configure socialite as and be familiar with this first.